# If $g \ge 0$ vanishing outside $(-1,1)$ with integral $1$ what is $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac 1t\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g\left(\frac xt\right)f(x)\,dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, riemann-integration

Let $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that

1. $g(x)\ge 0, \forall x \in \mathbb R$,
2. $g(x)=0, \forall |x| \ge 1$ and
3. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)\, dx=1 $

and let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be any continuous function. Then how to evaluate $$\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac 1t\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g\left(\dfrac xt\right)f(x)\,dx$$ From given, it is indeed true that $\int_{-1}^1g(x)\,dx=1$ and the given limit is equal to (assuming it exists) $$\lim_{t \to 0+}\int_{-t}^{t} g\left(\dfrac xt\right)f(x)\,d\left(\dfrac xt\right)=\lim_{t \to 0+}\int_{-1}^1g(z)f(tz)\,dz$$ but I cannot proceed further, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Next you use that $f$ is continuous at $0$. (You don't need that $f$ is continuous everywhere, continuity at $0$ is sufficient.) Write down what it means that $f$ is continuous at $0$ - the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition - and see how you can use that in the last integral.

Comment: $\frac 1 t g(\frac x t)\to \delta(x)$, so the integral converges to $f(0)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Ah huh !  Yes, so it should be $f(0)$ , right ?

Comment: @A.S. That's rather backwards. Showing that the integral converges to $f(0)$ is part of what one needs to show that in the sense of distributions $\frac{1}{t}g\bigl(\frac{x}{t}\bigr) \to \delta$.

Comment: @user228169 Correct, the limit is $f(0)$.

Comment: @Dan Not really. It's just a shorthand for $G(\frac x t)\to H(x)$ for all non-zero $x$. And convergence of cdfs implies convergence of integrals (we can assume that $f$ is supported on $[-1,1]$).

Comment: @A.S. No, it's not shorthand for $G\bigl(\frac{x}{t}\bigr) \to H(x)$ for $x\neq 0$. The latter is something that happens to be equivalent in the given setting, but the equivalence is a nontrivial theorem. In a problem dealing with Riemann integrals, I don't think knowledge of these facts can be assumed. (Aside remark: Please don't abbreviate my name to "Dan", I don't like that short form.)

Comment: @Daniel Yes, shorthand wasn't the right word and of course distributions/Lebesgue integral lie outside of Riemann integral (I didn't look at tags). You can still rewrite this very idea as $\int f(x)\,dG(\frac x t)\to \int f(x)\, dH(x)=f(0)$ for which we only need Riemann–Stieltjes integral. Because these things are so related, "backwards" seems like a misnomer.

Comment: @A.S. That's true. But I still think that "$f(tz) - f(0) \to 0$ uniformly on $[-1,1]$ if $f$ is continuous at $0$" is a much simpler argument.

Comment: @Daniel Simpler in a sense that most learn analysis before probability - yes (at this point I think probabilistic first, hence my answer). But not in other senses - since the approaches are basically identical. One compresses $g$ around $0$ and the other stretches $f$ "away" from zero instead. You don't even need uniform convergence you mentioned: just note that $$\min_{x\in[-t,t]} f(x)\le I\le \max_{x\in[-t,t]}f(x)$$ and you are done. To notice this, it really helped me to think of $\frac 1 t g(\frac x t)dt=dG(\frac x t)$ as a probability measure we integrate against.

Comment: @A.S. Well, we need also to note that $\max\limits_{x\in [-t,t]} f(x) \to I$ and ditto for $\min$ to conclude anything. And that is _exactly_ the uniform convergence of $f(tz)$ to $f(0)$ on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Daniel We don't. You just need to note that $\max_{x\in[-t,t]}f(x)\to f(0)$ by continuity - avoiding evoking a (more complex) notion of uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the mean value theorem for [definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_Mean_Value_Theorem_for_Definite_Integrals)

> If $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb R$  is continuous and $g$ is an integrable function that does not change sign on $[a, b]$, then there exists $c$ in $(a, b)$ such that
>   $$\int_a^b f(x) g(x) \, dx = f(c) \int_a^b g(x) \, dx$$

Your functions satisfy these assumptions, so for $(a,b)=[-1,1]$ you get that $$\int_{-1}^{1}g(z)f(tz)dz=f(tc)\int_{-1}^{1}g(z)dz=f(tz)$$ Taking the limit $t\to 0$, the RHS converges due to continuity of $f$ to $f(0)$.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:riemann-integration], that would make using the DCT at least difficult. Using the continuity of $f$ gets you a more elementary proof that works for Riemann integrals.

Comment: @DanielFischer You mean that I can use the mean value theorem for definite integrals?

Comment: No, just use the bound on $\lvert f(tz) - f(0)\rvert$ that you get from the continuity for small enough $t$. $$\int_{-1}^1 g(z)f(tz)\,dz - f(0) = \int_{-1}^1 g(z)\bigl(f(tz) - f(0)\bigr)\,dz$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Hm ok, I see, this works for sure as you say it. So as I have it above it is false again? It should be $f(c)$ rather than $f(tc)$ in my second expression?

Comment: Of course the mean value theorem works too with the assumption of continuity everywhere.

Comment: No, as you have it now it's correct. I just thought of a different way, so the answer to "You mean … mean value theorem" is "No, I meant something else".

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, thanks for checking it! Yes, I see what you meant in your previous comment.